# R - caret createDataPartition returns more samples than expected

Tags: r, dataset, r-caret

I'm trying to split the iris dataset into a training set and a test set. I used `createDataPartition()` like this:

```
library(caret)
createDataPartition(iris$Species, p=0.1)
# [1]  12  22  26  41  42  57  63  79  89  93 114 117 134 137 142

createDataPartition(iris$Sepal.Length, p=0.1)
# [1]   1  27  44  46  54  68  72  77  83  84  93  99 104 109 117 132 134
```

I understand the first query. I have a vector of 0.1*150 elements (150 is the number of samples in the dataset). However, I should have the same vector on the second query but I am getting a vector of 17 elements instead of 15.

Any ideas as to why I get these results?

Comment: I'm not sure why it does that. I'd solve it differently by `inds <- sample(1:nrow(iris), size=0.1*nrow(iris), replace=FALSE)` and then use `testdata <- iris[inds, ]` and `traindata <- iris[-inds, ]`. The `sample()` function does the same as `createDataPartition()` as far as I know, except that `createDataPartition()` takes into account that it creates a representative training dataset (some low values, some high value, etc.)

Comment: You asked why you get these results, and you got a detailed explanation - why don't you accept the answer??

Answer (score 3):

`Sepal.Length` is a numeric feature; from the online documentation:

> For numeric `y`, the sample is split into groups sections based on percentiles and sampling is done within these subgroups. For `createDataPartition`, the number of percentiles is set via the `groups` argument.
>
> `groups`: for numeric `y`, the number of breaks in the quantiles

with default value:

> `groups = min(5, length(y)`)

Here is what happens in your case:

Since you do not specify `groups`, it takes a value of `min(5, 150) = 5` breaks; now, in that case, these breaks coincide with the natural quantiles, i.e. the minimum, the 1st quantile, the median, the 3rd quantile, and the maximum - which you can see from the `summary`:

```
> summary(iris$Sepal.Length)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  4.300   5.100   5.800   5.843   6.400   7.900
```

For numeric features, the function will take a percentage of `p = 0.1` from *each one* of the (4) intervals defined by the above breaks (quantiles); let's see how many samples we have per such interval:

```
l1 = length(which(iris$Sepal.Length >= 4.3 & iris$Sepal.Length <= 5.1)) # 41
l2 = length(which(iris$Sepal.Length > 5.1 & iris$Sepal.Length <= 5.8))  # 39
l3 = length(which(iris$Sepal.Length > 5.8 & iris$Sepal.Length <= 6.4))  # 35
l4 = length(which(iris$Sepal.Length > 6.4 & iris$Sepal.Length <= 7.9))  # 35
```

Exactly how many samples will be returned from each interval? Here is the catch - according to line # 140 of the [source code](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/pkg/caret/R/createDataPartition.R#L140), it will be the *ceiling* of the product between the no. of samples and your `p`; let's see what this should be in your case for `p = 0.1`:

```
ceiling(l1*p) + ceiling(l2*p) + ceiling(l3*p) + ceiling(l4*p)
# 17
```

Bingo! :)